# 'something more like'

Tags: expressions, idioms

What does it mean when people say 'something more like'?
I saw this expression form the article, but I really just don't get it.
The full sentence is "Traditionally, something more like $50 has been the low end, with literary translation at around $120, and high-end work at $250."

Comment: If that was written by a native English speaker, it could only have been in a specialised context where the intention was more important than the language - often, for instance, financial commentary!

“… something more like $50” makes a contrast with something earlier, or the $120 following.

“something more like $50” here means “anything you’d like to work with that’s closer to $50 than $120…”

“$50” was specific; “more like $50” made it more generic; “something more like $50” is an attempt to avoid specificity…

Broadly, it boils down to “might we say, for the sake of argument…”

Answer (score 1):

It’s fairly common usage and it is a **correction of an approximation** in this context.

In your case, previous sentences may have given or implied a cost for (I guess) article translation. The quoted sentence splits the task into three different levels and gives a more accurate cost for each level. It could be replaced with the phrase **some cost closer to**.

A related phrase is ["That's more like it"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/More+like) where some reality is compared to an ideal.

Answer (score 0):

In this context consider: **in actuality** [TFD](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-actuality)

> used for emphasizing what is really true!

As in:

> "Traditionally, this item has cost *more like* $50, but in **actuality**, $120 and
>   even $250 at the high end are seen now."

'More like' is a guesstimate, versus actuality is what is found or prevalent.